# looping through dynamically created controls in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to use the following loop to loop through dynamically created controls on my web form:

```
            for(x = 0; x <= count; x++) {
                Stmt += $("#DDLColumns" + x).val();
                switch($("#DDLConditional" + x).val()) {
                    case "is equal": Stmt += " = ";
                        break;
                    case "begins with": Stmt += " LIKE '%";
                        break;
                    };
                Stmt += $("#WhereText" + x).val();
                Stmt += ", ";
            }
```

and this is producing undefined and nulls as output from the val() functions. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: without the HTML markup its going to be difficult to tell whats wrong.

Comment: Post your HTML please.  Or, rather, post how these elements are created.

Comment: As an aside, you *likely* have an of by one with `<= count`. Normally one would use `< count` with a 0-based index. Also use firebug or similar to ensure the DOM is what you expect, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have a `var Stmt` outside of the for loop to avoid scoping issues and return Stmt at the end of the function.

Comment: you guys are correct to ask for the html markup that was where the problem was I didn't have an id for the elements in question just a name attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider using different selectors to grab all of the DDLColumns with the [prefix selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-prefix-selector/).

Depending on what kind of elements DDLConditional is selecting you may be able to use the same style selector there but using the value attribute.

Pseudo code:

```
$('[id|=DDLColumns').each( function(i,value){
   $(value).find('[value|=is]').each( function(){
       Stmt += " = ";
   });

   $(value).find('[value|=begins]').each( function(){
       Stmt += " LIKE ";
   });

   // more stuff
});
```